# Modifying ANTLR4 Token

Tags: antlr4

My **Java.g4 grammar** is generating " /**\r\n\t *  A description Test. \r\n\t * \r\n\t * @see A first block tag\r\n\t * @see A second block tag\r\n\t */ " as a Token .

I'm rather interested in modifying my token permanently to **" A description Test. @see A first block tag @see A second block tag "** by means of **TokenStreamRewrite** or by some other way.

Any idea how to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

The tokens are actually CommonToken instance so you could cast them to that class and call setText(..) on them. However, I believe the lexer/parser is not the right place for this kind of work. Instead do that in the following phase (e.g. when walking over the parse tree) and extract the content of your doc-comment using simple string manipulation functions. Don't overload the generated classes with work that doesn't really belong to them.